# Problem using is_single() to enqueue script from functions.php

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags

I'm having trouble only adding scripts to single post pages. I need to both include and exclude certain scripts using is_single() but it doesn't work either way I try it.

I have the template tag on the top of custom single post templates...

```
<?php /* Template Name: Single Default */ ?>
```

And I use this to call a script from the functions.php

```
if (!is_admin()) {
 if (is_single()) {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-scroll', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/libs/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-scroll' );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be one of a few different issues.

### 1. Wrong Hook / Not Hooked

You need to make sure that `wp_enqueue_script` is hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Otherwise, the call can get fired too late or (possibly in this case?) too early?

Try this (also with your php cleaned up a bit:

```
function wpse53364() {
    if( !is_admin() && is_single() ) {
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-scroll', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/libs/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-scroll' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse53364' );
```

### 2. Incorrect Template Use

It's unclear from your question, but if you're using `single.php` for your "custom single posts template," you shouldn't be using that "Template Name:..." header. The WordPress [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) will automatically know which file to use.

### 3. Wrong Conditional Tag

The fact that you're using a custom page template makes me wonder whether you're trying to use this script to enqueue the script on PAGES as opposed to POSTS. If that's the case, you need to replace `is_single()` with `is_page()` or `is_singular( 'page' )`

Comment: I use a function that lets me put different single post templates into a folder in my child theme and then I call them conditionally from the single.php. Is that the problem?

Comment: Regarding the template, I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with that. Since [page's are the only post type that supports page templates](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12759) there's probably not much you can do if you need to recreate something similar.

Comment: The real root of the problem was not using an API hook to check the is_single() status. I think even the init hook is too soon for this (and the theme functions.php is loaded right before init fires), so I usually use the template_redirect hook for anything that depends on the is_*() conditionals.

Comment: `is_singular('custom_type');` worked for me