# Problem enqueuing scripts on not single posts

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I have this code to enqueue a script file when the page is not `single.php` (neither admin page):

```
//functions.php
/********************** Add JS file **************************/
function my_own_scripts() {
    if (! is_admin() && ! is_single()) {
        wp_register_script( 'my_javascript_file',get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/my_javascript_file.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_javascript_file' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_own_scripts' );
```

But the script is always enqueued. Also in a single post entry.

I've read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53364/problem-using-is-single-to-enqueue-script-from-functions-php), but doesn't help me. Of course, the theme is using `single.php` and `is_single()` works with other functions.

Any idea?

**Edit:**
I've found out that `is_single()` is always returning `false`, even when `single.php` is loaded. I can't see why this function is not working as expected while it is working right inside all other functions inside `functions.php`.

Comment: Don't use `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`. You should be using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

Answer (score 1):

With a couple minor modifications, I was able to run your function with your desired outcome (sitewide except on single post/cpt pages & in admin area).

The current preferred method of returning the stylesheet uri is with the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, *not* by using `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`:

> From the WordPress Codex [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo#Parameters) page:
>
> 'stylesheet_directory' - Returns the stylesheet directory URL of the active theme. (Was a local path in earlier WordPress versions.) Consider using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead.

The hook you are using, `wp_enqueue_scripts`, only loads the items in the front end - not the dashboard or login screen - by default (source: [WordPress Codex Plugin API Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)). Try the following modified version of your function, which worked when I tested it locally:

```
function my_own_scripts() {
    if (! is_single()) {
            wp_register_script ( 'my_javascript_file', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my_javascript_file.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
            wp_enqueue_script ( 'my_javascript_file' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_own_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, all makes sense except the "admin" part. I don't want to enqueue the file on admin pages. Anyway, the issue was resolved by changing the function name and the script name. Maybe it was overridden by the theme...

Comment: The`wp_enqueue_scripts` hook *only* enqueues scripts on the front end; there is a separate hook for enqueueing scripts in the admin, and a third that only enqueues on the login screens. For that reason, there is no need to include `!is_admin()` in your function. Regarding the naming convention, I would suggest using hyphens as spectators in filenames (aka, `my-javascript-file.js`). Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude both of these pages/sections you will have to check if the conditions are met for individual section too. Right not you are checking if both conditions are met with `AND` operator. What you need it `OR`.

Like this.

```
function my_own_scripts() {
    if ( !is_admin() || !is_single() ) {
        wp_register_script( 'my_javascript_file', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/my_javascript_file.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_javascript_file' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_own_scripts' );
```

Comment: I think you're wrong. I want to enqueue it if it's not admin page AND not single post.

Comment: No because both of these will never be true at the same time. That's why it's not working for you. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I've tried, but doesn't work. Think that I'm checking for  NOT true condition (!), so if it is NOT admin page AND it is NOT single post, it will be enqueued.

Comment: Try `is_singular()` instead. and see

Comment: Same thing... but yes, the problem is `is_single()`. I've updated my question.

Comment: BTW where are you check this on a page? or inside a post? I just tested it on my website and it's working fine. Are you sure this is not overwritten by any other function in your theme.

Comment: I'm looking inside a single post. This is a very weird thing. I've tried changing the function name and the script name, but anyway, the file is enqueued. If I replace `! is_single` with `is_single` the file is not enqueued. I'm really confused.

Comment: Oh man! Now it's working. May be when replacing the script name and the function name. Maybe the theme was overriding it somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Roberthue Your operator is wrong, the correct operator is `&&`. `!is_admin()` is always true on the front end, while `!is_single()` is always true except on the single post page. This is the only time that your complete condition returns false.